# this.cache not setting within Angular 2 HTTP calls

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm writing the following typescript and can't seem to set a value for cache:

```
@Injectable()
export class FundsService {

    private cache : Observable<Fund[]>;

    // Fetch all existing comments
    getFunds(useCache : boolean = true) : Observable<Fund[]> {

        // add authorization header with jwt token
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.token
        });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        // if cache set, return
        console.log(this.cache)
        if (useCache && this.cache) {
            console.log("using cache")
            return this.cache;
        }

        return this.http.get(this.fundsUrl, options)
            .map((res:Response) => {

                // store in cache
                console.log("setting cache")
                this.cache = res.json();
                console.log(this.cache)

                // return json
                return res.json()

            })
            .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    }
}
```

Is "this" the wrong this? When I check the compiled JS in TypeScript Playground I can see `var _this = this;`, seems OK to me. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: so you see `console.log("setting cache")` in the console?

Comment: and you're sure `useCache` is `true`?

Answer (score 0):

Try replace

```
 .map((res:Response) => {

 // store in cache
 console.log("setting cache")
 this.cache = res.json();
 console.log(this.cache)

 // return json
 return res.json()
}
```

by

```
 .map((res:Response) => res.json())
 .forEach(json => {
    this.cache = json
 })
```